# generate a list of products of a category

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing a shop application and I need to show products of each category. The problem is each product is created from a product template which is stored in a table and each template is related to a category. here is the product model:

```
    namespace fardashahr.Models
{
    [Table("Product")]
    public class ProductModel
    {
        public ProductModel()
        {
            if (Specs == null)
            {
                Specs = new Dictionary<string, SpecItemsModel>();
            }
        }
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ProductTemplateId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool IsPublished { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool InStock { get; set; }

        [Range(95, 110)]

        public float SyncRate { get; set; }


        public DateTime? ProductionDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime RegisterationDate { get; set; }

        public string ImageName { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<string> GalleryImages { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Dictionary<string, SpecItemsModel> Specs { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductTemplateId")]
        public virtual ProductTemplateModel ProductTemplate { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ManufacturerId")]
        public virtual CodingItemModel Manufacturer { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BrandId")]
        public virtual CodingItemModel Brand { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ModelId")]
        public virtual CodingItemModel Model { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SeriesId")]
        public virtual CodingItemModel Series { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is the the ProductTemplate:

```
    namespace fardashahr.Models
{
    [Table("ProductTemplate")]
    public class ProductTemplateModel
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
        public int Id { get; set; }


        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]  
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }


        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public virtual CategoryModel Category{ get; set; }

    }
}
```

and the controller is:

```
namespace fardashahr.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Products
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        public ActionResult Category(string name)
        {
            //declare a list of products
            List<ProductModel> productList;

            using(MainModel db = new MainModel())
            {
                //get category id
                CategoryModel category = db.Categories.Where(x => x.CategorytUrl == name).FirstOrDefault();
                int catId = category.Id;

                //initialize the list
                productList = db.Products.Where(x => x. == catId).ToList();
            }



        }
    }
}
```

finaly, what I want to know is how to initialize a list of products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your models, you added `virtual` keyword which indicates that navigation property will be automatically loaded without the need of LINQ lambda `.include()` expression.

Hence you can immediately access the navigation property and load the list like this;

```
productList = db.Products.Where(x => x.ProductTemplate.CategoryId == catId).ToList();

string categoryNameOfFirstProduct = productList.FirstOrDefault().ProductTemplate.Category.Name;

string categoryNameOfFirstProduct = productList.FirstOrDefault().ProductTemplate.Category.CategorytUrl;
```

Comment: If you're wondering what navigation properties are, these are examples of navigation properties; `public virtual ProductTemplateModel ProductTemplate { get; set; }` and `public virtual CategoryModel Category{ get; set; }`

Comment: thank you Jerdino very much. could you explain how to get a property from navigation property, for example the category name to use it in a viewbag?

Comment: @Arya for example you have a productModel object, you can do `string categoryName = productModel.ProductTemplate.Category.CategorytUrl;`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Will you include your controller wherein you're displaying the category name?

Comment: The reason for the whole question is I want to create a page for each category and show the products of that category. I think the controller you mentioned is included in the question and if not, please explain what controller do I have to include. I am a bit confused.

Comment: @Arya oh okay, so you need a sample view. Since you have navigational properties from Category to ProductModel, I think we could just make pass category/list category. Will you include the category model in the question?

Comment: Yes I think I need to.

Comment: Dear Jerdino, I am showing product list with your recommendation. thank you.

Comment: @Arya Were you able to make it work? If this helped you please mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Arya if this isnt solved yet, please include CategoryModel in your question